# In a mathematical induction, can you prove the "n'th case implies n+1'th case" step by contrapositive?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, induction, fibonacci-numbers

I'm attempting to prove the first part of Exercise 1.5, in Tom Apostol's *Mathematical Analysis*, regarding the Fibonacci numbers:

> The Fibonacci numbers $1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13 \dots$ are defined by the
>   recursion formula $x_{n + 1} = x_{n} + x_{n-1}$, with $x_1 = x_2 = 1$.
>
> Prove that $\gcd(x_{n}, x_{n+1}) = 1$.

The base case on the first two steps is pretty simple, of course: $\gcd(x_1, x_2) = 1$.

But I'm concerned I'm doing some weird pseudo-logical sleight of hand with the inductive hypothesis: Instead of proving directly that $\gcd(x_{n-1}, x_{n}) = 1$ implies $\gcd(x_{n}, x_{n+1}) = 1$, I find it easier to show that $\gcd(x_{n}, x_{n+1}) \neq 1 \implies \gcd(x_{n-1}, x_{n}) \neq 1$. This looks like a proof by contrapositive to me: $P$ implies $Q$, is equivalent to not $Q$ implies not $P$.

(Another way to phrase my argument, is that if $F_{n+1}$ and $F_{n}$ have a common factor $\alpha > 1$, then the definition of the Fibs implies that $\alpha \mid F_{n-1}$ as well, which implies $\alpha \mid F_{n-2}$, which implies $\alpha \mid F_{n-3}, \dots$, until we bottom out at the base cases, where this is clearly false. I have more than one way to phrase the thing, but I would rather stick to induction if it's legal, since I understand it a little better.)

Comment: Proof by contrapositive is fine.  You just have to prove $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$ by any legitimate means.

Comment: Of course, there is no problem with that. You need to show an implication, to do this you show a statement that you know is equivalent. No problem.

Comment: As you have found, one useful feature of the Fibonacci sequence is that, given two adjacent terms, you can generate it both forwards and backwards. So you could indeed frame this as an infinite descent type proof.

Comment: Thinking of induction the other way around is basically the "method of infinite descent".

Comment: @Hurkyl. Yes. That is what Fermat called  it.  If $\neg P(n)$ for some $n\in \Bbb N$  then there is a least such $n$. But if $(\forall m<n\in \Bbb N\;(P(m))\implies P(n)$ then there cannot exist a least $n$ such that $\neg P(n).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is fine, of course.

You can also do it directly. Assume $\gcd(x_{n-1}, x_n) =1$. Then $\exists \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\alpha x_{n-1} + \beta x_n = 1$.

We have

$$(\beta -\alpha)x_n + \alpha x_{n+1} = (\beta -\alpha)x_n + \alpha (x_n + x_{n-1}) = \beta x_n + \alpha x_{n-1} = 1$$
so $\gcd(x_n, x_{n+1}) =1$.